# LEFT join on secure view fails in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a normal view and one secure view and a table.

```
create or replace NORMALVIEW  as select click_id  FROM SECURE_VIEW a
LEFT JOIN
TABLE e
ON (e.click_id = a.google_click_id);


select * from NORMALVIEW;
```

I am getting the error:

> **SQL execution internal error: Processing aborted due to error 300002:2523989150; incident 8846932.**

other operations such as union is working

Comment: I am seeing the same error. Did you get an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you got an incident then you will need to open a case with Snowflake support to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

So I assume the SELECT part is valid:

```
select e.click_id 
FROM SECURE_VIEW a
LEFT JOIN TABLE e
    ON (e.click_id = a.google_click_id);
```

I also assume the view is actually defined more like:

```
CREATE table test.test.table_name (click_id int);

insert into test.test.table_name values (0),(1);

CREATE SECURE VIEW test.test.SECURE_VIEW AS 
    SELECT click_id as google_click_id 
    FROM test.test.table_name 
    WHERE click_id%2 = 1;

CREATE VIEW test.test.NORMALVIEW AS 
    SELECT click_id  
    FROM test.test.SECURE_VIEW AS a
    LEFT JOIN test.test.table_name  AS e
        ON e.click_id = a.google_click_id;
```

Or some other all valid stuff, thus those views would not be created. for the select to fail on.

I wonder if you grab the DDL of the view and try recreate then (with different names) if they are still valid, or if the shape of some underlying table changed, or if something as be drop/recreate/renamed..

```
SELECT * from NORMALVIEW;
```

But yes, at the point open a support ticket.